# Calling methods at object creation via constructor performance effect PHP

Tags: php, oop

My question is what is the best way in terms of performance. For example in the application bootstrap process i have a class

```
<?php 
class Application
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->setErrorHandler();
        $this->setDatabase();
        $this->sessionHandler();
        $this->disptachRequest();
    }

}
$app = new Application;
```

Is this a good approach or i should call these methods separately from the variable that holds the object?

I have set those function to `private` actually that is why i am calling them in constructor. Need guidance if this is good or bad?

Comment: Do all of those methods really take no arguments, or did you just leave them out to simplify the code for the question?

Comment: umm as of yet they are fine without arguments.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing inherently bad in it.

For performance, the question is, if all the calls are necessary in all cases. if not, you could defer them and execute them only if needed (this is called lazy loading)

For proper object oriented design the question is if the `Application` class and all its methods serve a common single responsibility. If not, break it down into smaller classes.